# Can't figure out SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository

I'm new to SVN and Maven. I am trying to download a source code from [websvn](http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=frascati&path=/trunk/examples/frascati-in-the-cloud/Google%20App%20Engine/). I've tried with Tortoise and SVN, both from desktop and Eclipse plug-in without success.

Doing it with

```
mvn http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=frascati&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Ffrascati-in-the-cloud%2FGoogle%20App%20Engine%2F
```

I get a prefix http error. What would be the way to download this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty convoluted how they provide anon access to the repo. If you read this wiki the things will be much clearer: [OW2 Forge: SVN Repository](http://forge.ow2.org/plugins/scmsvn/index.php?group_id=228)

You can check out project as (for your case)

```
svn checkout "svn://svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/frascati/trunk/examples/frascati-in-the-cloud/Google App Engine"
```

Please mind the quote around the URL since your URL contains white spaces.

or use tortoise to checkout `svn://svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/frascati/trunk/examples/frascati-in-the-cloud/Google App Engine`

---

**sidenote:** While reading your question, the one thing kept whining in my mind is why you would use `mvn` -- Maven, to checkout the repository.

Here is the distinction.

`svn` command is to invoke SubVersion. SubVersion is a SCM. It manages the revision, and parallel development. It has everything to do with checkout, checkin, update, delete, and add code to/from repository from/to your local machine.

`mvn` command is to summon the all mighty Maven. Maven is a build manager. It had to do with compiling, packaging, testing, and releasing of the code that you write. It partially overlaps with SVN (or any other SCM) during release. You do not use Maven to checkout the code.

So, `mvn` and `svn` do rhyme - but they aren't the same thing.

Comment: thx so much! I was going around that page already but couldnt figure out the right url. Thanks.